# I/O problem, Three input files use this code, but the first output file is currently finished other two showing garbage in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, sorting, io

I am trying to sort three files (I/O) using bubble sort. For this purpose, I write this code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

void bubble_Sort_ascending_order(ll n, ll v[]){
    ll i,j;
    for(i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=n-i; j++)
        {
            if(v[j]>v[j+1])
                swap(v[j],v[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

int bubble_Sort_ascending_input1() {

    freopen("input1.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output_File1.txt","w",stdout);

    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    ll t[n];
    for(ll i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin >> t[i];
    }

    bubble_Sort_ascending_order(n,t);

    for(ll k=1; k<=n; k++)
    {
        cout << t[k] << endl;
    }
}

int bubble_Sort_ascending_input2() {

    freopen("input2.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output_File2.txt","w",stdout);

    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    ll r[n];
    for(ll i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin >> r[i];
    }

    bubble_Sort_ascending_order(n,r);

    for(ll k=1; k<=n; k++)
    {
        cout << r[k] << endl;
    }
}

int bubble_Sort_ascending_input3() {

    freopen("input3.txt","r",stdin);
    freopen("output_File3.txt","w",stdout);

    ll n;
    cin >> n;
    ll v[n];
    for(ll i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        cin >> v[i];
    }

    bubble_Sort_ascending_order(n,v);

    for(ll k=1; k<=n; k++)
    {
        cout <<v[k]<<endl;
    }
}


int main(){
    bulble_Sort_ascending_input1();
    bubble_Sort_ascending_input2();    
    bubble_Sort_ascending_input3();
}
```

First input file function output is working properly. Second and third input function gives garbage value in output file two and three.

But I can't seem to locate any solutions to a similar problem. I'm really having trouble with understanding file I/O for some reason. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please format your code so it is readable and also see [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/3422102)

Comment: Why are you using `freopen` rather than `std::fstream`?

Comment: Read also the documentation of your C++ compiler (perhaps [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ....) and debugger (maybe [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/)...)

Answer (score 1):

This might not answer your question, but I see some flaws in your `bubble sort` algorithm. First of all, your indexing has to start at 0, otherwise you'll never read the first element in array, and then you can speed it up a little bit by right conditions in the for loop.

And then you could write `bubble_Sort_ascending_input()` method as just one with parameters such as `std::string input_file_name` and `std::string output_file_name`. Then you would more easily debug the program and see, where the problems are.

And for the love of gods, don't use `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`.

```
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

typedef long long ll;

void bubble_Sort_ascending_order(ll n, ll v[]) {
    ll i,j;
    for(i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
        for(j = 0; j < n - i -1; j++) {
            if(v[j] > v[j+1])
                swap(v[j], v[j+1]);
        }
    }
}

void bubble_Sort_ascending(const std::string& input_file, const std::string& output_file) {

    fstream input("../"+input_file, fstream::in);
    fstream output("../"+output_file, fstream::out);
    // "../" is just for IDE, if you run it from cmd, delete the path

    ll n;
    if (input.is_open()) {
        input >> n;
        ll arr[n];
        int i = 0;
        while (input >> arr[i]) {
            ++i;
        }
        bubble_Sort_ascending_order(n, arr);
        if (output.is_open()) {
            for (ll& number : arr) {
                output << number << " ";
            }
        }
    } else {
        cout << "input not open";
    }
}

int main() {
   bubble_Sort_ascending("input1.txt", "output1.txt");
   return 0;
}
```